# Range of Initial Sequence Numbers (ISNs) for TCP connection

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

I have many sources telling me that the range of ISNs are from 0 to 2^32 - 1 inclusive, example https://www.techopedia.com/definition/23554/initial-sequence-numbers-isn.

I don't understand why there's a minus one. Why can't the ISN be the value 2^32 as well?

I understand ISNs to be the first sequence number that initiates the connection between the client/server. Please let me know if I have any misconceptions.

Comment: Because there are only 32 bits available,, so it wouldn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence number is a 32 bit value. The possible values in a 32 bit value are from `0x00000000` (0) to `0xffffffff` (2^32-1). Having 2^32 inside it too would require counting from 1 instead of 0 or at least a 33 bit value.